# doubly indexed series with two different values when switching the index

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any example of double index sequences for which
$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n,m}=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{n,m}=\infty$.

Comment: If a series is converging but not absolutely, you can rearrange the summands to get an arbitrary sum, including $\infty$. So you can start with $\sum (-1)^n1/n$, make it a double sum and get a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example:
\begin{align}
a_{m,m} &= \frac{m(m+1)}{2},\\
a_{m+1,m} &= -\frac{m(m+1)}{2},\\
a_{n,m} &= 0 \text{ in all other cases}.
\end{align}

In the inner sums, almost all terms are 0, so we get:
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n,m} &= \sum_{m=1}^\infty (a_{m,m} + a_{m+1,m}) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\frac{m(m+1)}{2} - \frac{m(m+1)}{2}\right)= \sum_{m=1}^\infty 0 = 0,\\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{n,m} &= a_{1,1} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (a_{n,n-1} + a_{n,n}) = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(-\frac{(n-1)n}{2} + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)\\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n = \infty.
\end{align}